# Constraint optimisation

Tags: theoretical-biology

I have been asked to talk about (constrained) optimisation like $$\max_{x,y} f(x,y)$$ $$\mbox{Constrained by } g(x,y) = 0$$

for high school students with applications to biology. However, I can not think of a single good example from biology that actually uses optimisation.

The existing application is proving what the optimal linear regression line is given by, but this is rather tedious to do and not really a fun exercise for high school students, which is why I hope you might have a great application that I can use.

Comment: [Flux balance analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flux_balance_analysis) involves constraint based optimisation and it is frequently used to study metabolic systems and drug effects. I think it's interesting but high school students may still find it tedious and interesting examples of it may be too complicated for them.

Comment: The most "naive" models of evolutionary biology are optimisation models. Otherwise, in bioinformatics, there is plentiful of optimization problems.

Comment: @Remi.b Would you by any chance have a link for those naive models for evolutionary biology?

Comment: The most famous are Hamilton's rule (original paper: [Hamilton 1964](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022519364900396) which is a bit hard to read because of a terrible notation) and Price's equation ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Price_equation)). I called them "naive" because they are simple in the sense that they don't make consideration of statistical genetics nor molecular genetics.

Comment: Are you looking of examples of usage of optimization models to model biological processes or of the usage of optimization algorithm for inference problems (or any)?

Comment: Nothing specific. I am going to present the topic of optimisation for biology interested high school students, so I need some examples that I can use to argue why it is relevant.